# How to improve the performance of HoloLens when live streaming video from PC to HoloLens?

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I'm working on a HoloLens project and want to add a function that live streams screen shots from my PC to HoloLens. Luckily, I found a repository https://gist.github.com/jryebread/2bdf148313f40781f1f36d38ada85d47, which is very helpful. I modified a little bit of the python code on the client side to get screen capture on my PC and continuously send each frame to the HoloLens. However, the HoloLens performs poorly with the image receiver running, even a hand draggable cube cannot move smoothly and the whole frame rate drops.

I have tried to use the Holographic Remoting Player in Unity, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holographic-remoting-player. In this way, I only need to read the screen shots form my PC locally and send the whole rendered frame to HoloLens. However, when I play the Unity scene, the raw image contains screen shots shows up in Unity but not on the HoloLens.

I use IEnumerator load_image() and  StartCoroutine("load_image"); to load image from my computer. The code I use to load image and show on UI-RawImage is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class LiveScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    public RawImage rawImage;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        StartCoroutine("load_image");
    }

    IEnumerator load_image()
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"G:\Files\Pyfiles\", "*.jpg");                  // get every file in chosen directory with the extension.png
        WWW www = new WWW("file://" + filePaths[0]);                                    // "download" the first file from disk
        yield return www;                                                               // Wait unill its loaded
        Texture2D new_texture = new Texture2D(320, 180);                                // create a new Texture2D (you could use a gloabaly defined array of Texture2D )
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(new_texture);                                          
        rawImage.texture = new_texture;
        new_texture.Apply();
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me advice on how to improve the performance of the APP on HoloLens or whether I can use remote rendering of HoloLens for this project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately this community is not a search engine for external assets. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. 

However, there is an asset that might help you getting started: https://unitylist.com/p/fdt/u-Texture-Send-Receive it uses UDP to sync a texture between two Unity instances. Worked perfectly on the MagicLeap

Comment: You should record the screen locally on your PC and send it to Hololens as a streaming (like ffmpeg). If you use unity to develop your Hololens App, the link provided by derHugo shows how to play streaming media in Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the helping. Sorry this is the first time I ask question so I may make mistakes when I tried to describe it. This asset is cool. However, for this project, I have to use HoloLens and I have tested that this asset didn't work on HoloLens because some of the functions HoloLens use UWP instead. I will try ffmpeg and thanks a lot for the helping anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure inside the load_image() should theoretically work.

BUT it's a really bad practice to start a coroutine every update() frame loop.
Better start one coroutine and use a never ending loop with a WaitForSecond() break. This way you can try out what is the maximum repeat rate the hololens can handle.

```
void Start () {
     StartCoroutine(StartImageLoading());
 }

 IEnumerator StartImageLoading () {
     while(true){ // This creates a never-ending loop
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
         LoadImage();
         // If you want to stop the loop, use: break;
     }
 }
```

You should optimize your code inside load_images() too. Just load one file from disk if you want to show one image. That is much faster!

Comment: Thanks, this advice really helps.